# Unmarshal CSV to Struct and then Import

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Go.
I'm working to unmarshal CSV records into structs so that I can then create inserts and import this data into my DB.

I am looking for a way to automate marshaling, in a similar manner as encoding

When I run main, I am receiving an error

```
panic: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "id": invalid syntax
```

I've written some code which is supposed to unmarshal my .csv records to struct

```
func Unmarshal(reader *csv.Reader, v interface{}) error {
    record, err := reader.Read()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s := reflect.ValueOf(v).Elem()
    if s.NumField() != len(record) {
        return &FieldMismatch{s.NumField(), len(record)}
    }
    for i := 0; i < s.NumField(); i++ {
        f := s.Field(i)
        switch f.Type().String() {
        case "string":
            f.SetString(record[i])
        case "int":
            ival, err := strconv.ParseInt(record[i], 10, 0)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            f.SetInt(ival)
        default:
            return &UnsupportedType{f.Type().String()}
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

I created this struct in another file:

```
type InsertToDatabase struct {
    ID         int `csv:"id"`
    groupId    int `csv:"group_id"`
    Name    string `csv:"name"`
    Status int `csv:"status"`
}
```

When main is run, it should run this bit of code and then parse through my .csv file to create inserts, which are then ran on my local DB.

```
var InsertTest InsertToDatabase
    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    for {
        err := Unmarshal(reader, &InsertTest)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        channel <- InsertTest
    }
}
```

Is there a way to improve readability of this code? Also, should I  loop and call `.Read` to process one line at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run main, I am receiving an error
>
> panic: strconv.ParseInt: parsing "id": invalid syntax

I would guess you are parsing the header line of the CSV file by accident.